# Is there a way to re-declare a method from an other class?

Tags: java

*Sorry for the very noob question I'm new to this*

For example let say I have this code:

```
public class Amazing {
    public static void DoSomethingAmazing() {
        System.out.println("I did something amazing");
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Amazing.DoSomethingAmazing();
    }
}
```

Would it be possible for me to make so whenever Amazing.DoSomethingAmazing() is used it does something else (For example prints "I did not do something amazing" instead) without changing either the class the method is in or the class using it?

Comment: "it does something else without changing it?": something else like what?

Comment: either make the method static or declare the object of Amazing class in MainClass and then call the method with that object.

Comment: Downvoting as even the provided code is incorrect. Please edit your question. Also please define better what you mean by `Would it be possible for me to make so whenever Amazing.DoSomethingAmazing() is used it does something else without changing it?`

Comment: Without changing the `DoSomethingAmazing` method in `Amazing`? Easy - make another class called `Amazing` in a different package. And in the file MainClass.java, add/change the `import` statement to point to the other class that's also called `Amazing`.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Sorry for that, I edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Short answer: No, that is not possible. That would be a huge security risk and produce code that is near impossible to manage if anyone could just change what methods do without having to modify the original class.

Answer (score 2):

Closest you can get to this is by `extend`ing  `Amazing` class and overriding `DoSomethingAmazing` method, e.g.:

```
public class Amazing {
    public void DoSomethingAmazing() {
        System.out.println("I did something amazing");
    }
}

public class SomethingMoreAmazing extends Amazing {
   public void DoSomethingAmazing() {
        System.out.println("I did something more amazing");
    }
}
```

In the `main` method, you can do this:

```
Amazing a = new SomethingMoreAmazing();
a.DoSomethingAmazing();
```

It will print `I did something more amazing` i.e. it will make `DoSomethingAmazing` *do something else without changing it*.

You can read more about method overriding [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm).

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't make my question clear enough, the method DoSomethingAmazing was meant to be static and I meant to ask if there is a way to make so when it is used it does something else (For example prints "I did not do something amazing" instead) without changing the class the method is in and the class using it.

Comment: The answer to that is, No.